# GoogleApiClient: not firing onConnected or onConnectionFailed

Tags: android, google-api-client

So, I'm trying to get my last location using GoogleApiClient. I'm executing a connect statement, but onConnected is not firing, nor is onConnectionFailed firing. Any ideas?

Remark: I'm running this on an emulator, not a real device. Browsing on the emulator works.

```
package com.example.jdc.testjdc;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.*;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;



import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;
    private TextView Toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }
   // public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
       // mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){
        Log.e("Connected failed", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("Connected?", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.e("Connected?", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    }
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
           mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
           mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            TextView t=new TextView(this);

            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mLatitude);
            t.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            setContentView(mLatitudeText);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jdc.testjdc" >
    package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm at loss here. Through the debugger I've found that the above functions are never even fired...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register the callback in your method `buildGoogleApiClient()`.

Comment: @JohanDeCoster Please remember to accept the answer, StackOverflow is not a simple forum

Answer (score 10):

Try to change your buildGoogleApiClient() method

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

All you need it just add listeners to your client

```
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please explain what is happening with the change.

Comment: we set to googleApiClient listners for this actions .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this), so googleApiClient after connect returns callback to your listeners(addConnectionCallbacks, addOnConnectionFailedListener) in your class